# PySide Fullscreen Mac os x widget

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, pyside

Is there native support on a Qt fullscreen widget on the Main Window object in Mac Os X

I would like to add right top corner widget as seen on Google Chrome:

[image]

in my application:

[image]

I am aware of:

`self.showFullScreen()`

Answer (score 1):

I can't test this myself, but the Mac fullscreen button seems to be supported in Qt5 because there is a [window flag](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qt.html#WindowType-enum) for it:

```
Qt::WindowFullscreenButtonHint  0x80000000  On Mac OS X adds a fullscreen button.
```

Unfortunately, it does not look like this will ever be supported in Qt4, which is now effectively in feature-freeze (i.e. there probably will be no official Qt-4.9 release, contrary to some rumours that appeared a few years ago).